# How to override the ZKs "div.z-grid-header th.z-column" css?

Tags: zk

I need to make the wrap of column headers, as column headers alignment is going beyond limit. So for that I think we need to override "div.z-grid-header th.z-column" CSS class. But if I override the same at page level it is not allowing, throwing exception. I tried to override via ZK.xml as well but no luck. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>div.z-grid-header th.z-column, div.z-grid-header th.z-auxheader{
    white-space:normal;
    }
</style>
```

This solved my problem !

Answer (score 1):

You can easily override it in page level with the style tag in the zul :

```
<style>
    .z-grid-header {
        //your css
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Works but It does not solve my probelm.  I kept column headers fixed by setting grid CSSs position  attribute as absolute. But rows and column header are misaligning. How to solve this?

Comment: If you can create a fiddle, I can check it out